# Ugly fonts in Firefox with infinality

Tags: firefox, fonts

I recently installed truetype-infinality and infinality-fontconfig on my Xubuntu and set the rendering style to OSX. While my terminal and system fonts looks great, fonts on certain webpages look hideous in Firefox. For example, these Google search results and the section headers on wikipedia.

[image]
[image]

Anyone know what is causing this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to install [Ubuntu restricted extras](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/).[image: wink]

Also, I previously found [this](http://www.cufonfonts.com/downloadFont/12048/calibri.zip) if you want any Calibri fonts [image]

Comment: Image tags `![smiley](PATH-TO-IMAGE-ON-THE-WEB)` - I am only doing this while waiting for a download to finish, so I might as well have fun... @Sushantp606

Comment: Adblock Plus to the rescue :)

Answer (score 0):

Open your firefox and nevigate to -

**Edit > Preferences > Content** as shown below -

[image: Preferences]

And choose **serif** with font size **16** ..

Hope it helped you. Otherwise as Wilf has mentioned install Ubuntu-restricted-Extras if you did not have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` to get the MS Fonts:

> needed to install ubuntu restricted extras to get Microsoft fonts.

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```